# jquery mobile json var locale date

Tags: json, date, variables, jquery-mobile, locale

i have an application that sets a divider for the given dates. Everything works fine if the dates are in english but my dates are in dutch(NL) format where for example may=mei and february=februari.

How can i change my dates to english format or how can i set the divider using the epoch time (showing months)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#home').live('pagecreate', function() {
        $('#refresh').click(function() {
            $('ul').listview('refresh');
        });

        var data = { "users":[
        {
            "firstName":"First name",
                "lastName":"Last name",
                "joined": {
                    "date":"19 mei 2014",
                    "epoch":"1397400358"
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName":"First name",
                "lastName":"Last name",
                "joined": {
                    "date":"19 april 2014",
                    "epoch":"1397400358"
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName":"First name",
                "lastName":"Last name",
                "joined": {
                    "date":"18 april 2014",
                    "epoch":"1397400358"
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName":"First name",
                "lastName":"Last name",
                "joined": {
                    "date":"1 mei 2014",
                    "epoch":"1397400358"
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName":"First name",
                "lastName":"Last name",
                "joined": {
                    "date":"6 februari 2014",
                    "epoch":"1397400358"
                }
            }
        ]}

        data.users.sort();
        var dateList = $("#dates");
        for(var i=0, len=data.users.length; i<len; i++) {
    dateList.append("<li>"+data.users[i].joined.date+"</li>");  
        }

        dateList.listview({
            autodividers:true,
            autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
                var d = new Date(li.text());
                var month=new Array();
                        month[0]="januari";
                        month[1]="februari";
                        month[2]="maart";
                        month[3]="april";
                        month[4]="mei";
                        month[5]="juni";
                        month[6]="juli";
                        month[7]="augustus";
                        month[8]="september";
                        month[9]="oktober";
                        month[10]="november";
                        month[11]="december";
                return month[d.getMonth()];
            }
        }).listview("refresh");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use epoch like this, Write the epoch to the li as a data attribute:

```
for(var i=0, len=data.users.length; i<len; i++) {
    dateList.append("<li data-epoch='" + data.users[i].joined.epoch + "'>"+data.users[i].joined.date+"</li>");  
}
```

The in the autodviders code convert the epoch to date instead of the date string:

```
    dateList.listview({
        autodividers:true,
        autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
            var epoch = parseInt(li.data("epoch"));
            var d = new Date(epoch * 1000);
            var month=new Array();
                    month[0]="januari";
                    month[1]="februari";
                    month[2]="maart";
                    month[3]="april";
                    month[4]="mei";
                    month[5]="juni";
                    month[6]="juli";
                    month[7]="augustus";
                    month[8]="september";
                    month[9]="oktober";
                    month[10]="november";
                    month[11]="december";
            return month[d.getMonth()];
        }
    }).listview("refresh");
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ba66h/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Made a little change to your code if you have a json object like "epoch":"1397400358" you can use this.

```
var epoch = parseInt(li.data("epoch"));
var d = new Date(epoch * 1000);
```